# LibGDX simple 2d block map rendering

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to render a 2D block map, but its harder than I thought.

So lets see what I did

Created 2D array, the map :

```
map = new Block[w * h];
```

Block is very simple class that I created.. no worries.

Now I am actually trying to render it, very dumb way i know -

```
int WidthMapRender = ResX / Block.WIDTH;

int HeightMapRender = ResY / Block.HEIGHT;

for(int y = 0; y < HeightMapRender; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < WidthMapRender; x++) {
        int mapPos = ((player.posy - HeightMapRender / 2) + y) * Assets.map.width + ((player.posx - WidthMapRender / 2) + x);
        if(Assets.map.map[mapPos].TEXTURE != null) {
            batch.draw(Assets.map.map[mapPos].TEXTURE, (x * Block.WIDTH), (y * Block.HEIGHT), Block.WIDTH, Block.HEIGHT);
        }
    }
}
```

Holy Shit, I know, its the worst way to render a map, but I can't find a better way.
someone can help me out?
 I am really new to game development.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? What doesn't work? For creating and rendering of a 2D tile-based map, you can use TilEd and the TiledMapRenderers...

Comment: @IsraelG. did you solve your problem? Did you see my answer and did you try it? Do you stil have this issue?

Comment: @Springrbua Fixed it but your answer didn't help.. in fact i still have 1D array. i am using 1D array for performance.

Comment: Is 1D more performant? I always store tiled maps in 2D array, as i can directly use Arrayposition as worldpossition (array[x][y] == tile at (x,y)). It is also easy for collision detection, you just need to check the array at[yourX][yourY] to know if you collide or not.

Comment: @Springrbua Yes, 1D more efficient, especially if the map's length is more than 1M. my map is randomly generated and always expanding. which means it can store even more than 1M cells. so i must use 1D for sake of performance. But i changed my code so much since this post that its not relevant any more.

Comment: For randomgenerated, huge maps maybe chunk organisation would be good... I just don't like 1D Array approach... But if it works for you it is fine. Can you somehow post your solution and mark this as solved?

Comment: @Springrbua I use chunks.. but still i use 1D..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Tiled and TiledMapRenderer you could use a 2D Array instead of 1d.
`map = new Block[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT]`. If you use camera, what you actually should you don't need to have everything in pixels. You can use: `camera = new OrthographicCamera(MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT)`. And then set your SpriteBatchs projection Matrix to: `Batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)`. You now draw in cam coordinats. Note, that the cams 0,0 coordinate is now in the middle of the Screen, so move it with `camera.translate(MAP_WIDTH / 2, MAP_HEIGHT / 2)` and call `camera.update()`. The you can begin your Batch and draw the blocks in a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
        if (map[i][j] != null)
           batch.draw(blocktexture, i, j, 1(Width in your Worldunit), 1(Height in your Worldunit));
    }
}
```